# Output Raw HTTP Request without Sending in Ruby

Tags: ruby, http, httparty

I am trying to setup a POST request to a rest api using ruby. What I want to do is to output the raw HTTP request without actually sending the request. I have looked at HTTParty and Net:HTTP, but it seems the only way to output the request is only once you send the request. So basically I want a convenient way for creating an HTTP request string without actually having to send it.

Comment: if you are trying to make this for testing 3rd party service... and you want to mock this request (not sending the actual request to the 3rd party service but generate a response for this request locally) ... then i urge you to check https://github.com/bblimke/webmock

Answer (score 0):

The HTTParty.get and similar methods methods are helper functions that wraps a lot of the internal complexity; you should just peek inside the method to find that HTTParty.get to find that inside it it just [makes a call to perform_request](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/blob/master/lib/httparty.rb#L434):

```
def get(path, options={}, &block)
  perform_request Net::HTTP::Get, path, options, &block
end
```

and peeking into perform_request, we get that it just [constructs a Request object and call perform on it](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/blob/master/lib/httparty.rb#L495):

```
def perform_request(http_method, path, options, &block) #:nodoc:
  options = default_options.merge(options)
  process_headers(options)
  process_cookies(options)
  Request.new(http_method, path, options).perform(&block)
end
```

You should take a look into the Request class.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Already tried that, but internally in the Request class the method to create the request is private (setup_raw_request). I could open the class and change somethings, but that wouldn't be the ideal elegant solution I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Typhoeus](https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus)

```
request = Typhoeus::Request.new(
  "www.example.com",
  method: :post,
  body: "this is a request body",
  params: { field1: "a field" },
  headers: { Accept: "text/html" }
)
```

It allows you to create the request and then you can run it or not with

```
 request.run
```